# How to create a mocked HttpUrlConnection request for JUnit in Java

Tags: mocking, junit4

I've java servlet program, which taken input parameter as userId and talks to external system passing this userId and get response.

I want to write jUnit test case for this servlet class, but my jUnit test case should not talk to external system( which is httpurlConnection call) instead I want to mock that and get response.

How I can achieve this using jUnit? It would be really appreciated if someone can help on this?

Answer (score 0):

From the [ThoughtWorks Radar](https://www.thoughtworks.com/radar) there is something that might be useful, although it might prove difficult to use if your a beginner: [Mountbank](http://www.mbtest.org/)  and [example](http://brandonbyars.com/2014/02/10/stubbing-a-mule-tcp-connector-with-mountebank/) .